# How to have some data from SQL Query with JOINS

Tags: sql

I have a problem with joins...

I have 3 tables, the first table is called `Ordenes`, the second `Cables`, and the third `Operaciones`

So the columns that i want from the query is:
`NoOrden, NoParte, Cantidad, Faltan`

I already have a query and it works, but it have a problem, because it only shows me the results that have at least one relation with the table `Operaciones`.
So if some row of the table `Ordenes`, doesn't have at least one cable, the query isn't gonna show me that row, and i don't want that, I want that if the row of the table `Ordenes` doesn't have at least one cable in the table `Cables`, show me in the `Faltan` column of the query the actual quantity of the `Ordenes` column.
Sorry for my bad english, i hope that your understand me.
This is the query that it have:

```
SELECT 
Ordenes.NoOrden, Ordenes.NoParte, Ordenes.Cantidad, 
(Ordenes.Cantidad - COUNT(Cables.IdCable)) AS Faltan 
FROM Ordenes 
INNER JOIN Cables ON Ordenes.IdOrden = Cables.IdOrden  
INNER JOIN Operaciones ON Cables.IdOperacion = Operaciones.IdOperacion 
WHERE 
Operaciones.Nombre NOT IN('Scrap') AND Ordenes.Estado = 'Abierta' 
GROUP BY Ordenes.NoOrden, Ordenes.NoParte, Ordenes.Cantidad;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want an outer join:

```
SELECT o.NoOrden, o.NoParte, o.Cantidad, (o.Cantidad - COUNT(c.IdCable)) AS Faltan
FROM Ordenes o LEFT JOIN
     Cables c
     ON o.IdOrden = c.IdOrden LEFT JOIN
     Operaciones op
     ON c.IdOperacion = op.IdOperacion AND
        op.Nombre NOT IN ('Scrap') 
WHERE o.Estado = 'Abierta'
GROUP BY o.NoOrden, o.NoParte, o.Cantidad;
```

Note that the condition on `Operaciones` needs to go into the `ON` clause instead of the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: It show me now all okay, but it have a problem in the "Faltan" column, it show me negative numbers, because it is not excluding the op.Nombre (Scrap)

Comment: You can use `COUNT(op.idOperation)` instead of `COUNT(c.idCable)`.

Comment: But, if i do that, i'm gonna count the operations, not?, i want to count all the cables per operations excluding the cables that have the operation 'scrap'.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you will need to use a Left join instead of an inner join:

Left JOIN Cables ON Ordenes.IdOrden = Cables.IdOrden

Left JOIN Operaciones ON Cables.IdOperacion = Operaciones.IdOperacion